# PostgreSQLFunction with two select statements

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, procedure

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL function declaring two variables to return on each one the result of a different query, the query themselves are really simple, and rely on the same select with different conditions:

```
select count (*) from editions where year >= '2000'
```

and

```
select count (*) from editions where year < '2000'
```

The structure of the table is also simple, there are three rows:

1. Code (numeric)
2. Version (character)
3. Year (integer)

How can I create this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so basic.. I think you can find many tutorial in Google to create this `Function`.. And your `Year` column are `Integer` so don't treat like `String` use `Single Quote`..

*Function totalRecords1()*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalRecords1()
RETURNS integer AS $total1$
declare
    total1 integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into total1 
   FROM your_table
   WHERE year >= 2000;
   RETURN total1;
END;
$total1$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Function totalRecords2()*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalRecords2()
RETURNS integer AS $total2$
declare
    total2 integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into total2 
   FROM your_table
   WHERE year < 2000;
   RETURN total2;
END;
$total2$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And `Select Statement`

```
select totalrecords1(), totalrecords2();
```

You can see here in [**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=11349019594cabe00746b2f3dca57bd7)

Comment: Glad to help.. :)